# Add class but after click removes class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, jQuery `addClass` code add class to my div but after click class is gone. It is a multi page website.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".left-menu-icon").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("l-animals-a");
  });
});
```

```
<a href="animals.html">
  <div class="left-menu-icon l-animals"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Looks like you're clicking a link and not firing off an `event.preventDefault`, so you're loading a new page that's why you don't see the class there.

Comment: So you want to add a class to the current menu link? If yes, `preventDefault` as other suggest is not an answer.

Comment: I know, do you know any solution, i'm not that good in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

As [Culyx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807060/add-class-but-after-click-removes-class#comment38505938_24807060) correctly commented: What is happening here is that your click on the `<a>` tag is actually redirecting you to the `animals.html` page. I assume that this is the page you are currently on so what actually is happening is the page is refreshing.

You will have to prevent the page from performing the redirect by trapping the event in the click event:

```
$(".left-menu-icon").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass("l-animals-a");
});
```

In order to capture the event, I'm using the [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) function. The MDN documentation describes this function as follows:

> Cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

Comment: Thanks, the refresh is the problem but this code you provided me but it doesn't work. I have 14 menu buttons that lead to 14 different pages, is there any way fore me to add active class to menu whet it's active? Active state changes background image.

Comment: What is your menu element? You didn't reference it in your post. This sounds to me like a different question...

Comment: Well it is a different question now, sorry. The a tag with div inside that I posted is first button of menu, in that menu there is 14 same buttons but different href link. When I use your code I can't switch between my pages because click on a tag wont work now.

Comment: Oh - I see what you mean... What you'll have to do is notify your page (possibly from within the server), what page you are on. This way the server is actually deciding which menu element is active.